# Event Listener for click event on multiple buttons of same name but different value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

EDITED FIXED AND WORKING:
Jquery and bootstrap do not allow same ID - see the new UI and Jquery code below:

Previously attempted to completely separate onclick events from UI as recommended by latest security practices. The use of repeat ID in Jquery and Javascript create bad mojo for onclick events even with use of 'this' - instead use chained class (empty class) behind Twitter bootstrap classes and tie onclick to new custom class. This eliminates in-line on-click event.

UPDATED UI Code:

```
//Grid Row 1 with record info preceeding
<td>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs cust_delete' id='btn_delete_record_1' name='btn_delete_record_1' value="X38-721" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#DeleteRecordModal'>
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>
</button>
</td>

//Grid Row 2 with record info preceeding
<td>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs cust_delete' id='btn_delete_record_2' name='btn_delete_record_2' value="X34-7245" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#DeleteRecordModal'>
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>
</button>
</td>
```

JQUERY -

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.cust_view').click(function() { 
        var myRecord = $(this).attr('value');
        $("#view_record_id").val(myRecord);
        $('form#frm_view_record').submit();
    }); 
    $('.cust_delete').click(function() { 
        var myRecord = $(this).attr('value');
        $('#delete_record_id').val(myRecord);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Can not use this method as Jquery and Javascript require unique ID - changing to add custom class chained to twitter bootstrap

Comment: I don't think it's a good way to hack with JS. You really should try to figure out why duplicated IDs are output in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll()` to loop through all the occurences of a button with a name of "button" and `addEventListener()`s to them.  The buttons can have different values, but it checks for the name only:

```js
var linkListener = document.querySelectorAll("button[name='button']");

for (i=0;i<linkListener.length;i++){
  linkListener[i].addEventListener("click", linkFunction);
  }

function linkFunction(){
  
  alert("You clicked a button with a \"name\" of \"button\".");
  
  }
```

```html
<button name="button">A button</button><button name="button">A button</button><button name="button">A button</button><button name="button">A button</button><button name="button">A button</button><button name="button">A button</button><button name="button">A button</button><br/><br/>

<button name="button1">A button</button><button name="button2">A button</button><button name="button3">A button</button><button name="button4">A button</button><button name="button5">A button</button><button name="button6">A button</button><button name="button7">A button</button>
```

Comment: the linkFunction inserts appropriate links to each attribute?? Value?? - trying to have button UI produced via a PHP function within table to give new number otherwise I will have to create complex pass back.

Comment: Modify it to your liking.  Using a loop would be the easiest way to go here.

Comment: I might even suggest using an array with different values to loop through.

Comment: I guess I am not sure how you on each pass of the loop are grabbing the value from the button (changing on each loop to the value of the button being counted in that loop pass.)

Comment: Thank you for the help - but see above had to use jquery with custom class instance and unique ID for each button.

Comment: I see.  I'm glad you were able to get it to work.  The reason that I could loop is because queryAllSelector() returns an array.